# Get total number of lines of a Method in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, methodinfo

I have a requirement to get the total number of lines from a particular method.
I have following code:

```
 MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typelist[i].GetMethods();
 from methodInfos[0]
```

How can I get it?

Comment: What do you mean by "lines"? Count?

Comment: suppose i have a method having 50 line of code .. then using MethodInfo class i want to get total lines

Comment: I afraid when the program is being compiled and executed, it may be not possible to get the information of the source code.

Comment: I think its possible to do this if you can access to the source code when the program is running.

Comment: Do you really need to do this yourself? You can get Visual Studio to do it, from the Main Menu choose Analyze -> Calculate Code Metrics For Solution, which gives a LOC count calculated from the IL.

Answer (score 3):

You *can't do that*, e.g. these methods will be compiled into *same* IL code

```
// One line 
public static void Sample() {
  Console.Write("abc"); Console.Write("def");
}

// Two lines 
public static void Sample() {
  Console.Write("abc"); 
  Console.Write("def");
}

// Three lines 
public static void Sample() {
  Console.Write("abc"); 
  // Some comment
  Console.Write("def");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

MethodInfo is part of .NET reflection. This will give you any information you'll need to know concerning the type model of .NET. Unfortunately (?!?) the number of code lines **doesn't** belong to that information. The type model is independent from the language you'd chosen to write the method. If you want to know the no of code lines, you will have to take a different approach. (ReSharper plugin or rosalyn)

Answer (score 1):

### WARNING: This is not recommended, I'm just simulating it with a tricky/hacky way!

You can throw 2 exceptions and get lines.

I wrote some (tricky) code below:

```
public class Program
{
    private static int first = 0, second = 0;
    private static void Log(Exception ex, bool last = false)
    {
        var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
        var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
        if(last)
        {
            second = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
            Console.WriteLine("Total lines: {0}", second - first);
        }
        else
        {
            first = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
        }
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
        try { throw new Exception("Ex1"); } catch(Exception ex) { Log(ex); }

        int a = 5;
        string b = "text";
        bool c = false;

        try { throw new Exception("Ex2"); }catch(Exception ex) { Log(ex, true); }
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Test();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

So, it'll simply get exception line numbers and substract them, and we have the line count!

**Edit:** Also, I think it won't be always true because compiler will do some optimizations, JIT too etc. (I'm not barely remember this process sorry) and it may be incorrent but this is close.